# Cannot get the infoWindow width to do calculation for making the content to the center of the InfoWindow

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps, infowindow

I have removed close button of infoWindow of google map with using jquery,but cannot get the infoWindow width to do calculation for making the text at the center of the InfoWindow.

Remove close button:

```
var iw_nextNode = $(".gm-style-iw").next() 
iw_nextNode.remove();
```

That is the way how I try to get infoWindow's width

```
var iw_container = $(".gm-style-iw").parent();
iw_container.attr('class', 'iw_con');
$(".iw_con").width()
```

However, it return the width of the class "gm-style-iw" which is the content's width

```
$(".gm-style-iw").width()
```

Is there any way to get the infoWindow's width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your map is similar to [this map](http://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/infowindow-simple) .. you can get the `width` of the **InfoWindow** using :

```
$(".gm-style-iw").parent().width();
```

---

### Update:

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nXsf7/3/embedded/result/) .. (**Note**: the width is printed in the console in your browser)

[Source](http://jsfiddle.net/nXsf7/3/) ..

it works perfectly using :

```
$(".gm-style-iw").parent().width();
```

Take a look at [the source code of the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nXsf7/3/) and then check your code maybe you made a mistake somewhere ..

Hope this will help you ..

Comment: i have tried it before, but it get $(".gm-style-iw").width()

Comment: @user2352577 I've updated my answer.. take a look at it

Comment: It is really works, thank you so much.
That is what i use your solution:
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow,'domready',function(){
        var iw_container = $(".gm-style-iw").parent();
        iw_container.attr('class', 'iw_con');
        infowindow_width=$(".iw_con").width()
          console.log(infowindow_width);
//            alert(infowindow_width);
        });